# TypeError in Tkinter callback when adding PatchCollection to matplotlib Axes3D

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

The following code is adapted from the Polygon example [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.add_collection3d).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection, PatchCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')


def cc(arg):
    return mcolors.to_rgba(arg, alpha=.6)

zs = range(4)
patch_list = []
for z in zs:
    patch = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 10, 10, color=cc('r'))
    patch_list.append(patch)

patch_collection = PatchCollection(patch_list, match_original=True)
ax.add_collection3d(patch_collection, zs=zs, zdir='y')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 4)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 10)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

It worked fine for the PolyCollection, but when I switched to a PatchCollection I started getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 590, in callit
        func(*args)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 370, in idle_draw
        self.draw()   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 351, in draw
        FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 464, in draw
        self.figure.draw(self.renderer)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 63, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1144, in draw
        renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
        a.draw(renderer)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 271, in draw
        for col in self.collections]   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.py", line 387, in do_3d_projection
        vxs, vys, vzs, vis = proj3d.proj_transform_clip(xs, ys, zs, renderer.M)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 207, in proj_transform_clip
        return proj_transform_vec_clip(vec, M)   
File "/home/csquires/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/proj3d.py", line 164, in proj_transform_vec_clip
        vecw = np.dot(M, vec) TypeError: can't multiply

sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Looks like it has to do with the backend - any recommendations on what to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Patch3DCollection instead of PatchCollection.

Import Patch3dCollection with:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Patch3DCollection
```

and change PatchCollection to Patch3dCollection, i.e.

```
patch_collection = Patch3DCollection(patch_list, match_original=True)
```

Comment: This made the patches get plotted, but now I'm getting a floating rectangle that isn't attached to any axis (i.e. when I spin the plot around, it stays in the same place)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment to Jannick, using a Patch3DCollection still gave me problems, not attaching the patches to the graph properly. Instead, I needed to create each patch individually, add it to the axis, and then change it to 3d:

```
zs = range(4)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']
for i, z in enumerate(zs):
    rect = patches.Rectangle(xy=(0, 0), width=10, height=10, color=cc(colors[i]))
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    art3d.patch_2d_to_3d(rect, z=z, zdir='y')
```